# c++ boost iterator throwing assert and programme terminates

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

I get the following error at this line:

```
const short pcmSample = *reinterpret_cast<const short*>(*(buffer->index));
```

`buffer` is an object of class `accumlator`.

Here I am trying to convert a byte array into shorts. The code throws this runtime error and terminates.

```
class accumlator : public boost::circular_buffer<char>
{
  public:
    boost::circular_buffer<char>::iterator index;
};
```

i have initialized the iterator to point to begin of buffer

and `index` is a iterator to circular buffer.

> boost::cb_details::iterator::reference
>   boost::cb_details::iterator::operator*() const [with
>   Buff = boost::circular_buffer, Traits =
>   boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits >,
>   boost::cb_details::iterator::reference = char&]:
>   Assertion `m_it != 0' failed.

i have even tracked this to the file boost/circular_buffer/detail.hpp

the assert condition checks - if iterator is pointing to end.
if it is pointing to end then it throws the assert.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I indented, capitalized and fixed you question. Please remember that the more effort you put in your question, the more likely you will get an answer.

Comment: Thank u very much ereOn,i will definitely try to improve my questions representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't assign index to a value. The operator* is doing a runtime check to make sure it's pointing to valid (non-0) value.

Comment: i have initialized index to point to the begin of circular buffer but the assert and error are thrown because index is pointing to end,

Comment: That would imply begin() == end(). What does circular_buffer contain? Can you iterate through it and print out the content using begin() and end()?

Comment: circular buffer contains char type of data.yes ofcourse data is present in buffer i have streamed them into a file as well.

Comment: It means you need to post more of your code or give the simplest possible failing example. Checking the circular_buffer code, only way begin() can return a 0 iterator is when empty() call returns true. So when you set index to begin() can you test the empty()?

Comment: thank u very much akhisp the exception was thrown because we were initializing index in constructor at that time buffer was empty so it was returning 0.so when i was using it in function it was throwing error,thank u very much for the help.